# How to construct multiple spark dataframes and run in parallel?

Tags: scala, azure, apache-spark, azure-eventhub

I have a dataframe read from Cassandra say having 1 million records. I need to load to event hubs. Since there is an upper limit in event hubs, it's not fast enough. So I thought let load to multiple event hubs.

```
json.select("body").write.format("eventhubs").options(eventhubConfig.toMap).save()
```

So I can pass 1 event hub config at a time. So splitting of dataframe should help, but this happens one by one, i.e. another df is processed after the first one is done.

Suggest a solution where I will be able to write to multiple event hubs in parallel. I tried with row insert but its quite slow.